# Put into executable function in matlab

Tags: string, matlab, function, system

very good day all,

I am new to matlab, I am not familiar with most of the matlab function guys and wish can get some tips from you..

The problem is I want one of the system function to be executed. More precisely, I ask a user to **input a string and I want to pass this string to my function that executes the string and return to me the output**

for instance

```
input: dog
```

pass the dog to `!wn`

The function should be in this form `!wn dog 'parameter'`  . Executable function. I want to execute this function not return me the `!wn dog 'parameter'`. In matlabe command it is working if i use the system function and then use this

```
>> !wn dog param
```

the above command is working in the command environment but if i want an input from a user and put the input into that function and execute it and i expect the output to be like. Just want to know how to make it executable from a mat file

I tried to do this

```
 keyword= 'dog'; % 

  x = system('wn'); % this to execute the system function

  output= strcat('!wn',  keyword)
```

Your kind answer is highly appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: In `x = system('wn');`, the output `x` is not the result returned by `wn`. See the help. The first output is the return status, which can be used to determine if the function generated an error or completed successfully. You need to get the second argument to see the output -see my answer.

Comment: The other thing you tried won't work, because it just creates a string. You can turn this into something that works, but it's bad programming style and inefficient -don't do it: `result = evalc(['!wn ' keyword])`. Note also that I just used simple square braces (`[` and `]`) instead of `strcat` to join the strings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if the [`!`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_env/creating-opening-changing-and-deleting-files-and-folders.html#f0-38522) form of calling system functions is going to work in your case. It seems to be designed mainly as [a shortcut to be used in the command window and provides no means of capturing output](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_env/creating-opening-changing-and-deleting-files-and-folders.html#f0-38522). However, you can use the [`system`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/system.html) function like this:

```
[~,result] = system(['wn ' input ' ' params]);
```

or you can generalize it a bit and turn it into a function:

```
function result=call_wn(input,varargin)
[status,result] = system(['wn ' input sprintf(' %s',varargin{:})]);
```

This allows a variable number of parameters, including none. `input` is required. I'm guessing that you're on Windows (I have no idea what the "wn" command is), so also check out [`dos`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/dos.html).

Comment: FYI, you'll probably wan't to avoid using a variable called `input` in any actual implementation as that is also the name of a [builtin Matlab function](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/input.html) - which could even be useful in your case and easily combined with the above code.

Comment: Thank you so much horchler .. You are really an expert.. I would like to to know you maybe we can exchange emails or facebook.. I am working on matlab